# Remove LetterSpacing in TextViews for a specific language

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a newbie in Android development and a newbie in programming for that matter.

I am working on an android application that has several languages including Thai. My colleague has applied letterSpacing throughout the whole application but I have got to deactivate it for Thai language only. How would you achieve that?

I have tried below solution but it's not working:

```
 private boolean isThaiLanguage() {
        return Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("th");
      }

    private void applySpacing() {
    if (this == null || this.originalText == null) return;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < originalText.length(); i++) {
      builder.append(originalText.charAt(i));
      if (i + 1 < originalText.length()) {
        if (!isThaiLanguage()) {
          builder.append("\u00A0");
        }
      }
    }

    SpannableString finalText = new SpannableString(builder.toString());
    if (builder.toString().length() > 1) {
      for (int i = 1; i < builder.toString().length(); i += 2) {
        finalText.setSpan(new ScaleXSpan((spacing + 1) / 10), i, i + 1,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);


      }
    }

    super.setText(finalText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
  }
```

Below are is the code that my colleague has successfully applied for letterSpacing.

Thanks a million ;)
Hinda
PS: do let me know if you need further information to solve this problem. I'll be happy to help.

```
public class LetterSpacingButton extends Button {
  public static final String TAG = "LetterSpacingButton";

  private float spacing = Spacing.NORMAL;
  private CharSequence originalText = "";
  private TextView text;

  public LetterSpacingButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public LetterSpacingButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initLetterSpacing(context, attrs);
  }


  public LetterSpacingButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initLetterSpacing(context, attrs);
  }

  private void initLetterSpacing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme()
        .obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LetterSpacing, 0, 0);

    try {
      this.spacing = a.getFloat(R.styleable.LetterSpacing_letterSpacing, 0);
    } finally {
      a.recycle();
    }
    this.originalText = super.getText();

    applySpacing();
  }

  public float getSpacing() {
    return this.spacing;
  }

  public void setSpacing(float spacing) {
    this.spacing = spacing;
    this.originalText = super.getText();

    applySpacing();
  }

  @Override
  public void setText(CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type) {
    originalText = text;

    applySpacing();
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getText() {
    return originalText;
  }

  private void applySpacing() {

    if (this == null || this.originalText == null) return;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < originalText.length(); i++) {
      builder.append(originalText.charAt(i));
      if (i + 1 < originalText.length()) {
          builder.append("\u00A0");

      }
    }

    SpannableString finalText = new SpannableString(builder.toString());
    if (builder.toString().length() > 1) {
      for (int i = 1; i < builder.toString().length(); i += 2) {
        finalText.setSpan(new ScaleXSpan((spacing + 1) / 10), i, i + 1,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);


      }
    }

    super.setText(finalText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
  }

  public class Spacing {
    public final static float NORMAL = 0;

  }
}
```

2nd File:

```
public class LetterSpacingTextView extends TextView {

    private float spacing = Spacing.NORMAL;
    private CharSequence originalText = "";
    private boolean isQuickStart1 = false;


    public LetterSpacingTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LetterSpacingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
        initLetterSpacing(context, attrs);
      }


    public LetterSpacingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initLetterSpacing(context, attrs);
      }


    private void initLetterSpacing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      TypedArray a = context.getTheme()
          .obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LetterSpacing, 0, 0);

      try {
        this.spacing = a.getFloat(R.styleable.LetterSpacing_letterSpacing, 0);
      } finally {
        a.recycle();
      }
      this.originalText = super.getText();
       initLetterSpacing(context, attrs);
        applySpacing();

      }

    }

    public float getSpacing() {
        return this.spacing;
    }

    public void setSpacing(float spacing) {
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.originalText = super.getText();
        applySpacing();
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        originalText = text;
        if(isQuickStart1){
           applySpacingQS1();
        }else{

          applySpacing();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getText() {
        return originalText;
    }

    private void applySpacing() {
        if (this == null || this.originalText == null) return;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < originalText.length(); i++) {
            builder.append(originalText.charAt(i));
            if(i+1 < originalText.length()) {
                builder.append("\u00A0");
            }
        }

      SpannableString finalText = new SpannableString(builder.toString());
        if(builder.toString().length() > 1) {
            for(int i = 1; i < builder.toString().length(); i+=2) {
                finalText.setSpan(new ScaleXSpan((spacing+1)/10), i, i+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
        super.setText(finalText, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }

    private void applySpacingQS1() {
        if (this == null || this.originalText == null) return;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < originalText.length(); i++) {
            builder.append(originalText.charAt(i));
            if(i+1 < originalText.length()) {
                builder.append("\u00A0");

             }
            }
        }
        SpannableString finalText = new SpannableString(builder.toString());
        if(builder.toString().length() > 1) {
            for(int i = 1; i < builder.toString().length(); i+=2) {
                finalText.setSpan(new ScaleXSpan((spacing + 1) / 10), i, i + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                int indexNote = builder.toString().indexOf("T H E   N O T E S");
                if(indexNote!=-1){
                    finalText.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), indexNote, indexNote+"T H E   N O T E S".length(), 0);

                }
            }
        }
        super.setText(finalText, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }

    public class Spacing {
        public final static float NORMAL = 0;
      public final static float STANDARD = -1;
    }

    public void setIsQuickStart1(Boolean isQuickStart1) {
        this.isQuickStart1 = isQuickStart1;
    }
}

EXAMPLE OF THE IMPLEMENTATION OF LETTERSPACING IN LAYOUT:

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <RelativeLayout
      android:background="@color/white"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingLeft="32dp"
      android:paddingStart="32dp"
      android:paddingRight="32dp"
      android:paddingEnd="32dp"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      tools:context="com.smartsoftasia.perfume.view.activity.RegisterActivity">


    <com.smartsoftasia.perfume.view.component.LetterSpacingTextView
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/perfumist"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        custom:letterSpacing="3"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/accent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <com.smartsoftasia.perfume.view.component.LetterSpacingTextView
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/perfume_advisor"
        custom:letterSpacing="1"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:textColor="@color/black_secondary_text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


    <com.smartsoftasia.perfume.view.component.LetterSpacingTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        custom:letterSpacing="1"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black_text"
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <EditText
        style="@style/edit_text_grey"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_activity_register_email"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_your_password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <EditText
        style="@style/edit_text_grey"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_activity_register_fist_name"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_fist_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_activity_register_email"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <EditText
        style="@style/edit_text_grey"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_activity_register_last_name"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_last_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_activity_register_fist_name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <Spinner
        style="@style/edit_text_grey"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_activity_register_gender"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_gender"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_activity_register_last_name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <EditText
        style="@style/edit_text_grey"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_activity_register_city"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_city"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_activity_register_gender"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <EditText
        style="@style/edit_text_grey"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_activity_register_date_of_birth"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_date_of_birth"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_activity_register_city"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <EditText
        style="@style/edit_text_grey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_activity_register_password"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_activity_register_date_of_birth"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <EditText
        style="@style/edit_text_grey"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_activity_register_confirm_password"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_confirm_password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_activity_register_password"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>


    <com.smartsoftasia.perfume.view.component.LetterSpacingButton
        style="@style/button_accent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        custom:letterSpacing="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_activity_register_register"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_activity_register_confirm_password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

    <com.smartsoftasia.perfume.view.component.LetterSpacingButton
        style="@style/button_alpha"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:id="@+id/button_activity_register_cancel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_activity_register_register"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who wants to apply letter spacing which is the blanc space in between letters and wants it removed for a particular language or for that matter for any other textviews, here is the solution:

LetterSpacingTextView.java:

```
private boolean isThaiLanguage() {
    return Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("th") ;
  }

private void applySpacingQS1() {
    if (this == null || this.originalText == null) return;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < originalText.length(); i++) {
      builder.append(originalText.charAt(i));
      if (i + 1 < originalText.length()) {
        if (!isThaiLanguage()) builder.append("\u00A0");
      }
    }

    SpannableString finalText = new SpannableString(builder.toString());
    if (builder.toString().length() > 1)

    {
      for (int i = 1; i < builder.toString().length(); i += 2) {
        if (!isThaiLanguage()) {
          finalText.setSpan(new ScaleXSpan((spacing + 1) / 10), i, i + 1,
              Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
          int indexNote = builder.toString().indexOf("T H E   N O T E S");
          if (indexNote != -1) {
            finalText.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), indexNote,
                indexNote + "T H E   N O T E S".length(), 0);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    super.setText(finalText, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
  }
```

LetterSpacingButton.java:

```
private boolean isThaiLanguage() {
    return Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("th") ;
  }

private void applySpacing() {

    if (this == null || this.originalText == null) return;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < originalText.length(); i++) {
      builder.append(originalText.charAt(i));
      if (i + 1 < originalText.length()) {
        if (!isThaiLanguage()) {
          builder.append("\u00A0");
        }
      }
    }

    SpannableString finalText = new SpannableString(builder.toString());
    if (builder.toString().length() > 1) {
      for (int i = 1; i < builder.toString().length(); i += 2) {
        if (!isThaiLanguage()) {
          finalText.setSpan(new ScaleXSpan((spacing + 1) / 10), i, i + 1,
              Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
      }
    }

    super.setText(finalText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
  }
```